# Cannot get the user details once the registration process is complete in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am building a simple [blog application](https://github.com/tharakabimal/blog-app/issues/1) using Meteor and ReactJS. And I'm using react-komposer to make it reactive. The issue I'm having is related to the user registration/Login process. **accounts-base, accounts-password** are the two Meteor packages I'm using to handle register & login functionalities.

Here's my **LoginHeader** component

```
import React from 'react';

const LoginRegister = () => (
    <div>
        <a href="/login" className="navbar-link">Login  | </a> 
        <a href="/register" className="navbar-link">Register </a>
    </div>
);

const LoginHeader = (user) => (
   <div>        
     <p className="navbar-text navbar-right">
        {user ? user.user.emails[0].address : <LoginRegister />}
     </p>       
   </div>
);

export default LoginHeader;
```

This is the **LoginHeader** container

```
import LoginHeader from '../components/login_header.jsx';
import {useDeps, composeAll, composeWithTracker, compose} from 'mantra-core';

export const composer = ({context}, onData) => {
  const {Meteor, Collections} = context();

  var user = Meteor.user();

  onData(null, {user});
};

export const depsMapper = (context, actions) => ({
  context: () => context
});

export default composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composer),
  useDeps(depsMapper)
)(LoginHeader);
```

What's weired about it is that **user.user.emails[0].address** worked for a while and all of a sudden it started giving me the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined**.

Help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: How to make this question better: (1) show the code here and not in your gh repo, (2) describe what is not working and how you expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have had the same problem. Are you sure the user is loaded? See the following question:

[What am I doing wrong when manipulating data in Meteor/MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682580/what-am-i-doing-wrong-when-manipulating-data-in-meteor-mongodb/36683591#36683591)

And make sure to find the sure path that Michel Floyd pointed out. Check the structure of your user collection in MongoDB.

Comment: I also think this is an interesting link:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users

All fields in the collection on the server doesn´t get published to the client automatically. You may have to specify which other fields you want.

Answer (score 0):

If `user = Meteor.user()` then the email address is at `user.emails.address[0]` not `user.user...`

Comment: when I do that I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**.

Comment: Try `console.log(user)` and see what you get.