# What am I doing wrong when manipulating data in Meteor/MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this helper

```
myClub: function(){
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: currentUserId});
    return user;
}
```

I want it to return user.role

Here is my user in MongoDB

```
{
    "_id" : "RdirmrLG3t8qBk4js",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-04-17T19:40:56.877Z"),
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$cPe92XR9DT238bH/RanYEu.J6K2ImvAEbWOcVq6j9luI0BH08Qdly"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2016-04-17T19:51:49.474Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "uVKUj/7JEkkOuizXhjl212Z38E47HXCex+D4zRikQ1k="
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "username" : "worker",
    "role" : "worker",
    "club" : "hzSKAJfPXo7hSpTYS"
}
```

The code above works just fine. So it finds the current user and outputs info about it. But when I change user to user.role I get the following errormessage.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined
>       at Object.myClub

How can it be undefined? Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: I can manage to output or check tor username of the user now but not the role. But can it ha something to do with the structure. When I run 

Meteor.users.find().fetch();

in the console I get this
>Object
id :"RdirmrLG3t8qBk4js"
username :"worker"
>__proto__:Object

So it seem logical that the username can be retrieved with user.username. But the role is not on the same level. I can't even find role in the structure. Why and where do I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
myClub: function(){
  return Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().role;
}
```

This is shorthand for *return the role if there's a user*.

As far as the `role` field not showing up, make sure that you are *publishing* that key from the server and subscribing to it. For example:

```
Meteor.publish('me',function(){
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId,{fields: {role: 1, username: 1, profile: 1, emails: 1}});
});
```

And on the client:

```
var me = Meteor.subscribe('me');
if ( me.ready() ) console.log("Ta-da! The role is: "+Meteor.user().role);
```

Comment: Isn't (there is a user) = (a user has logged in)?

The code dosen´t return anything so in that case I guess there is no user. But I have logged in with a user and it has a role.

Comment: The user object can take a few milliseconds to load so you can be logged in and not have a user object but you will have a `userId`.

Comment: Ok. But I still have problem finding the role-field in the userdocument. I updated my question a while ago.

Comment: I also put the role and all other stuff in profile in Accounts.createUser which made me able to retrive it.

Answer (score 1):

Template helpers are reactive, which means they update themselves as the app state changes or new data appears. In your case, the helper is called immediately when the template is rendered and before the `Meteor.users` collection is filled. Therefore, the `.findOne()` method returns undefined. It will be corrected in the second pass after new data arrives.

The simple fix here is to check whether the data is present inside the helper:

```
myClub: function(){
  var currenUserId = Meteor.userId();
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: currenUserId});
  if(!user) return 'NO DATA';
  return user.role;
},
```

In real life you'll probably want to wait for the basic data to be loaded before you render the template. That is usually done on the controller level.

Comment: Ok. I get the idea. Now I don´t get any error but it doesn't output anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you subscribed to all data you need.

By the way, you can try following:

```
role: function(){ return (Meteor.user() || {}).role; }
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Suspected the subscriptions. But I still have autopublish in this project. Can subscriptions really be an issu then?

Comment: If you keep the autopublish package in your project there's shouldn't be any problems with a subscriptions.